# Which 2's complement integer operations can be used without zeroing high bits in the inputs, if only the low part of the result is wanted?

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, integer, twos-complement

In assembly programming, it's fairly common to want to compute something from the low bits of a register that isn't guaranteed to have the other bits zeroed.  In higher level languages like C, you'd simply cast your inputs to the small size and let the compiler decide whether it needs to zero the upper bits of each input separately, or whether it can chop off the upper bits of the result after the fact.

This is especially common for x86-64 (aka AMD64), for various reasons<sup>1</sup>, some of which are present in other ISAs.

I'll use 64bit x86 for examples, but the intent is to ask about/discuss [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and unsigned binary arithmetic in general, since [all modern CPUs use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931630/how-are-negative-numbers-represented-in-32-bit-signed-integer).  (Note that C and C++ don't guarantee two's complement<sup>4</sup>, and that signed overflow is undefined behaviour.)

As an example, consider a simple function that can compile to an `LEA` instruction<sup>2</sup>.  (In the x86-64 SysV(Linux) [ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html)<sup>3</sup>, the first two function args are in `rdi` and `rsi`, with the return in `rax`.  `int` is a 32bit type.)

```
; int intfunc(int a, int b) { return a + b*4 + 3; }
intfunc:
    lea  eax,  [edi + esi*4 + 3]  ; the obvious choice, but gcc can do better
    ret
```

gcc knows that addition, even of negative signed integers, carries from right to left only, so the upper bits of the inputs can't affect what goes into `eax`.  Thus, [it saves an instruction byte and uses](http://goo.gl/h3UKGC) `lea  eax,  [rdi + rsi*4 + 3]`

#### What other operations have this property of the low bits of the result not depending on the high bits of the inputs?

And why does it work?

---

---

### Footnotes

**<sup>1</sup> Why this comes up frequently for [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)**:
 x86-64 has variable-length instructions, where an extra prefix byte changes the operand size (from 32 to 64 or 16), so saving a byte is often possible in instructions that are otherwise executed at the same speed.  It also has false-dependencies (AMD/P4/Silvermont) when writing the low 8b or 16b of a register (or a stall when later reading the full register (Intel pre-IvB)):  For historical reasons, [only writes to 32b sub-registers zero the rest of the 64b register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).  Almost all arithmetic and logic can be used on on the low 8, 16, or 32bits, as well as the full 64bits, of general-purpose registers.  Integer vector instructions are also rather non-orthogonal, with some operations not available for some element sizes.

Furthermore, unlike x86-32, the ABI passes function args in registers, and upper bits aren't required to be zero for narrow types.

**<sup>2</sup> LEA:** Like other instructions, the default operand size of [LEA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7071164/224132) is 32bit, but the default address size is 64bit.  An operand-size prefix byte (`0x66` or `REX.W`) can make the output operand size 16 or 64bit.  An address-size prefix byte (`0x67`) can reduce the address size to 32bit (in 64bit mode) or 16bit (in 32bit mode).  So in 64bit mode, `lea eax, [edx+esi]` takes one byte more than `lea eax, [rdx+rsi]`.

It is possible to do `lea rax, [edx+esi]`, but the address is still only computed with 32bits (a carry doesn't set bit 32 of `rax`).  You get identical results with `lea eax, [rdx+rsi]`, which is two bytes shorter.  Thus, the address-size prefix is never useful with `LEA`, as the comments in disassembly output from Agner Fog's excellent objconv disassembler warn.

**<sup>3</sup> x86 ABI**: 
The caller *doesn't* have to zero (or sign-extend) the upper part of 64bit registers used to pass or return smaller types by value.  A caller that wanted to use the return value as an array index would have to sign-extend it (with `movzx rax, eax`, or the special-case-for-eax instruction `cdqe`.  (not to be confused with `cdq`, which sign-extends `eax` into `edx:eax` e.g. to set up for `idiv`.))

This means a function returning `unsigned int` can compute its return value in a 64bit temporary in `rax`, and not require a `mov eax, eax` [to zero the upper bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register) of `rax`.  This design decision works well in most cases: often the caller doesn't need any extra instructions to ignore the undefined bits in the upper half of `rax`.

---

#### <sup>4</sup> C and C++

C and C++ specifically do *not* require two's complement binary signed integers (except for [C++ `std::atomic` types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith2)).  [One's complement and sign/magnitude are also allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2931680/224132), so for *fully* portable C, these tricks are only useful with `unsigned` types.  Obviously for signed operations, a set sign-bit in sign/magnitude representation means the other bits are subtracted, rather than added, for example.  I haven't worked through the logic for one's complement

However, [bit-hacks](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) that [only work with two's complement](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs) are [widespread](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Average%20of%20Integers), because in practice nobody cares about anything else.  Many things that work with two's complement should also work with one's complement, since the sign bit still doesn't change the interpretation of the other bits: it just has a value of -(2<sup>N</sup>-1) (instead of 2<sup>N</sup>).  Sign/magnitude representation does not have this property: the place value of every bit is positive or negative depending on the sign bit.

Also note that C compilers are allowed to assume that signed overflow *never happens*, because it's undefined behaviour.  So e.g. [compilers can and do assume `(x+1) < x` is always false](http://goo.gl/h3UKGC).  This makes detecting signed overflow rather inconvenient in C.  [Note that the difference between unsigned wraparound (carry) and signed overflow](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Wide operations that can be used with garbage in upper bits:

- bitwise logicals
- left shift (including the `*scale` in `[reg1 + reg2*scale + disp]`)
- addition/subtraction (and thus `LEA` instructions: the address-size prefix is never needed.  Just use the desired operand-size to truncate if needed.)
- The low half of a multiply.  e.g. 16b x 16b -> 16b can be done with a 32b x 32b -> 32b.  You [can avoid LCP stalls (and partial-register problems) from `imul r16, r/m16, imm16`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111959/packing-bcd-to-dpd-how-to-improve-this-amd64-assembly-routine) by using a 32bit `imul r32, r/m32, imm32` and then reading only the low 16 of the result.  (Be careful with wider memory refs if using the `m32` version, though.)

  As pointed out by Intel's insn ref manual, the 2 and 3 operand forms of `imul` are safe for use on unsigned integers.  The sign bits of the inputs don't affect the N bits of the result in a `N x N -> N` bit multiply.)
- 2<sup>x</sup> (i.e. shift *by* `x`):  Works at least on x86, where the shift count is masked, rather than saturated, down to the width of the operation, so high garbage in `ecx`, or even the high bits of `cl`, don't affect the shift count.  Also applies to BMI2 flagless shifts (`shlx` etc), but not to vector shifts (`pslld xmm, xmm/m128` etc, which saturate the count).  [Smart compilers optimize away masking of the shift count, allowing for a safe idiom for rotates in C (no undefined behaviour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c).

Obviously flags like carry/overflow / sign / zero will all be affected by garbage in high bits of a wider operation.  x86's shifts put the last bit shifted out into the carry flag, so this even affects shifts.

#### Operations that *can't* be used with garbage in upper bits:

- right shift
- full multiplication: e.g. for 16b x 16b -> 32b, ensure the upper 16 of the inputs are zero- or sign-extended before doing a 32b x 32b -> 32b `imul`.  Or use a 16bit one-operand `mul` or `imul` to inconveniently put the result in `dx:ax`.  (The choice of signed vs. unsigned instruction will affect the upper 16b in the same way as zero- or sign-extending before a 32b `imul`.)
- memory addressing (`[rsi + rax]`): sign or zero-extend as needed.  There is no `[rsi + eax]` addressing mode.
- division and remainder
- [log2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272424/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling) (i.e. position of highest set bit)
- trailing zero count (unless you know there is a set bit somewhere in the part you want, or just check for a result larger than N as you not-found check.)

---

Two's complement, like unsigned base 2, is a place-value system.  The MSB for unsigned base2 has a place value of 2<sup>N-1</sup> in an N bit number  (e.g. 2<sup>31</sup>).  In 2's complement, the MSB has a value of -2<sup>N-1</sup> (and thus works as a sign bit).  [The wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) explains many other ways of understanding 2's complement and negating an unsigned base2 number.

The key point is that **having the sign bit set *doesn't change the interpretation of the other bits***.  Addition and subtraction work exactly the same as for unsigned base2, and it's only the interpretation of the result that differs between signed and unsigned.  (E.g. [signed overflow happens when there's a carry into but not out of the sign bit](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).)

In addition, carry propagates from LSB to MSB (right to left) only.  Subtraction is the same: regardless of whether there is anything in the high bits to borrow, the low bits borrow it.  If that causes an overflow or carry, only the high bits will be affected.  E.g.:

```
 0x801F
-0x9123
-------
 0xeefc
```

The low 8 bits, `0xFC`, don't depend on what they borrowed from.  They "wrap around" and pass on the borrow to the upper 8 bits.

**So addition and subtraction have the property that the low bits of the result don't depend on any upper bits of the operands.**

Since `LEA` only uses addition (and left-shift), using the default address-size is always fine.  Delaying truncation until the operand-size comes into play for the result is always fine.

(Exception: 16bit code can use an address-size prefix to do 32bit math.  In 32bit or 64bit code, the address-size prefix reduces the width instead of increasing.)

---

Multiplication can be thought of as repeated addition, or as shifting and addition.  The low half isn't affected by any upper bits.  In this 4-bit example, I've written out all the bit-products that are summed into the low 2 result bits.  Only the low 2 bits of either source are involved.  It's clear that this works in general:  Partial products are shifted before addition, so high bits in the source never affect lower bits in the result in general.

See [Wikipedia for a larger version of this with much more detailed explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier#More_advanced_approach:_signed_integers).  There are many good [google hits for *binary signed multiplication*](https://www.google.ca/?q=binary%20signed%20multiplication), including some teaching material.

```
    *Warning*: This diagram is probably slightly bogus.


       ABCD   A has a place value of -2^3 = -8
     * abcd   a has a place value of -2^3 = -8
     ------
   RRRRrrrr

   AAAAABCD * d  sign-extended partial products
 + AAAABCD  * c
 + AAABCD   * b
 - AABCD    * a  (a * A = +2^6, since the negatives cancel)
  ----------
          D*d
         ^
         C*d+D*c
```

---

**Doing a signed multiply instead of an unsigned multiply still gives the same result in the low half** (the low 4 bits in this example).  Sign-extension of the partial products only happens into the upper half of the result.

This explanation is not very thorough (and maybe even has mistakes), but there is good evidence that it is true and safe to use in production code:

- gcc uses `imul` to compute the `unsigned long` product of two `unsigned long` inputs.  [See an example of this of gcc taking advantage of LEA for other functions on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Aint+intfunc(int+a,+int+b)+%7B+return+a+%2B+b*4+%2B+3%3B+%7D%0A%0Along+longfunc(int+a,+int+b)++++++++++%7B+return+a+%2B+b*4+%2B+3%3B+%7D%0Along+longfunc_longa(long+a,+int+b)+++%7B+return+a+%2B+b*4+%2B+3%3B+%7D%0Along+longfunc_longb(int+a,+long+b)+++%7B+return+a+%2B+b*4+%2B+3%3B+%7D%0Along+longfunc_longboth(long+a,+long+b)%7Breturn+a+%2B+b*4+%2B+3%3B+%7D%0A%0Aunsigned+long+longmul(unsigned+int+a,+unsigned+int+b)+%7B+return+(unsigned+long)a+*+(unsigned+long)b%3B+%7D%0A%0A//+signed+overflow+is+undefined+behaviour:+compilers+optimize+by+pretending+it+doesn!'t+happen%0Aint+overflow_check(int+x)+%7B+return+(x%2B1)+%3C+x%3B+%7D%0Aint+carry_check(unsigned+x)+%7B+return+(x%2B1)+%3C+x%3B+%7D'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).
- Intel's insn ref manual says:

> The two- and three-operand forms may also be used with unsigned
>   operands because the lower half of the product is the same regardless
>   if the operands are signed or unsigned. The CF and OF flags, however,
>   cannot be used to determine if the upper half of the result is
>   non-zero.

- Intel's design decision to only introduce 2 and 3 operand forms of `imul`, not `mul`.

---

Obviously the bitwise binary logical operations (and/or/xor/not) treat each bit independently: the result for a bit position depends only on the inputs value at that bit position.  Bit-shifts are also rather obvious.