# Is there an advantage of using rxx registers over exx for decoding CPUID?

Tags: assembly, x86, inline, cpu-registers

I keep finding myself programming on my 64bit OS using eax, etc., yet rax works the exact same. Is there any benefit to writing inline assembly in exx vs rxx? If anything exx is compatible across platforms and saves marginal time from using predefined processor macros to change between exx and rxx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In what context?  If you need to hold an address, obviously you need a 64bit register (unless using the x32 ABI or other method to ensure addresses fit into 32 bits).

Otherwise, if you don't need a 64bit operand size, use 32bit because it's the default.  64 require a REX prefix, 16 requires an operand-size prefix byte, while 8 just uses a different opcode.

In many cases, you can use the default 32bit operand / 64bit address size [even if you only want a smaller result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in).  e.g. `lea eax, [rdi + rsi*4 - 15]` always gives identical results to `lea eax, [edi + esi*4 - 15]`.  That Q&A covers (and links to) some background on operand-sizes, which might shed some light on things if you're finding it non-obvious.

Comment: For reference, I've been using 32 bit registers with the opcode cpuid to determine if a hypervisor is present. Would it have any benefit to use R in that scenario?

Comment: @Revolt: as you can see from the insn ref manual (linked from the x86 tag wiki), CPUID only writes to `eax/ebx/ecx/edx`, even in 64bit mode.  `This instruction operates the same in non-64-bit modes and 64-bit mode.`  Obviously this makes it easier for everyone: people writing code to decode the results, and people writing the implementation that goes inside the CPU microcode.  So yes, you absolutely should just use 32bit registers / operand size for testing CPUID result bits.

Comment: Also note that [gcc has builtins for testing CPUID now, since at least gcc 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html).  See the examples using e.g. `__builtin_cpu_supports("avx")`

Comment: I was not aware of `__builtin_cpu_supports`. That's good to know! MSVC has it's own intrinsic. What about Clang and ICC. It seems easier to using inline assembly rather than rely on a builtin for each compiler (with MSVC 64-bit that's the only option though).

Comment: @Zboson: clang implements GNU C extensions, and defines a macro to say what version of GNU C it supports.  Just check the GNU C VERSION with an `#ifdef`.