# Preventing AX register being clobbered by DIV instruction

Tags: assembly, division, multiplication, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to solve these simple multiplication and division operations in assembly.

```
5*4 + 35/7
```

I have done this

```
mov al,5
mov bl,4 
mul bl 

mov ax,35 
mov bl,7 
div bl
```

My previous value for multiplication in the *AX* register is overwritten with a new result from division. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you writing 16-bit 8086 code targeting DOS or EMU8086?

Comment: I am writing this for emu8086 ..yes 16bit

Answer (score 2):

Emu8086 is based on 8086 instructions so you only have the single operand versions of *MUL* and *DIV*. Just to make you aware, [IMUL](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html) is the signed version of [MUL](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html), and [IDIV](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html) is the signed version of [DIV](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html). Assuming you intended to do unsigned arithmetic your code could look like this:

```
mov al,5
mov bl,4 
mul bl 
mov cx, ax     ; Save AX to CX

mov ax,35 
mov bl,7 
div bl

xor ah, ah     ; Result(quotient) of DIV in AL, ensure AH is zero
add ax, cx     ; AX=AX+CX
```

There is no way to prevent *AX* from being destroyed with the 8086 specific instructions of *MUL* and *DIV*. You'll have to move the value to a scratch area. We'll use the register *CX* for that in the code above. Since we save the result of the *MUL* instruction to *CX* we just need to add it to the result of the *DIV* instruction (where the quotient is in *AL*). We zero out the remainder stored in *AH*, leaving the quotient in *AL*. *AX* would now contain the quotient (as a 16-bit value) that we add to *CX*, and the final result of the equation is stored in *AX*.

---

A simplification for multiplying by 4 is to shift a value left 2 bits. This code:

```
mov al,5
mov bl,4 
mul bl 
mov cx, ax     ; Save AX to CX
```

Can be reduced to:

```
mov cx, 5
shl cx, 2      ; Multiply CX by 4
```

The 8086 processor doesn't support *SHL* shifting more than 1 bit except through the *CL* register. EMU8086's assembler automatically translates the `SHL reg, imm` instruction to one or more `SHL, reg, 1` instructions. In this case `SHL CX, 2` was translated to:

```
shl cx, 1      ; Multiply CX by 2
shl cx, 1      ; Multiply CX by 2 again
```

Most 8086 assemblers will not do this translation for you. Alternatively, the number of bits to shift can be specified in the *CL* register. This (or the equivalent) would work with most 8086 assemblers:

```
mov cl, 2      ; Number of bits to shift left by in CL
mov dx, 5
shl dx, cl     ; Shift DX to the left by CL(2) is equivalent to multiply by 4

mov ax,35 
mov bl,7 
div bl

xor ah, ah     ; Result(quotient) of DIV in AL, ensure AH is zero
add ax, dx     ; AX=AX+DX
```

Comment: The `shl cx, 2` is __not__ a 8086 instruction! Only single shifts are allowed.

Comment: @Fifoernik That is true, but the question is also tagged EMU8086 (per the OPs comment). One place EMU8086 diverges from the 8086 is that the assembler supports SHL by an immediate value (other than 1), but internally produces multiple SHL by 1 instructions. I amended my answer to make that clarification

Comment: So when you say "internally", you mean at assemble time?  If you were single-stepping your code, you'd see repeated `shl cx` instructions?  Your wording makes it sound like it handles the `imm8` count encoding.  If it's just syntactical sugar in the assembler, any assembler could do that for 8086 targets if it wanted to.  It may happen that emu8086 is the only 8086 assembler that does this, but it works in emu8086 because of its assembler, not because it's "not a real 8086 processor".

Comment: Yes if you bring it up in the debugger you'll discover that the one instruction gets translated to multiple shift instructions. It isn't that the underlying architecture supports the enhanced shift instruction, the assembler takes liberties to generate the equivalent although potentially inefficient translation

Comment: Emu8086 is an anomaly since it is an integrated assembler and runtime environment. The same software that assembles also debug and emulates. A typical user who isn't aware of this likely would never notice the translated instruction unless they look at the raw machine code generated.

Answer (score 2):

> My previous value for multiplication in the AX register is overwritten with a new result from division. How do I fix this?

Simple enough. Put the result from the multiplication in an extra register (I used `DX`), calculate the next term of the expression, finally add both results. It's important to note that the quotient is **only** in the `AL` register, so you need to clear the `AH` register before doing the addition! (*The numbers used in the example "35/7" yield a remainder of 0 in `AH` but you should not count on this when asked to write a program!*)

```
mov al,5
mov bl,4
mul bl     ; -> Result is in AX
mov dx, ax

mov ax,35 
mov bl,7 
div bl     ; -> Result is in AL

mov ah, 0
add ax, dx ; -> Final result is in AX
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to multiply 5 * 4 and then push the value onto the stack.  Then do your second calculation, the division.  Then pop the first value off of the stack and add the values together.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, and it's been awhile, but I believe that the problem may be that al is half of ax.  So when you move a value into ax it overwrites al.  In other words, al and ah are the low and high bits of ax.

Comment: There's no need to use the stack, but your general point is correct that the OP clobbers the mul result (which does ax=al*src) with `mov ax,35`.  x86 has 7 general purpose registers (not counting the stack pointer, which can be used as general-purpose, but never is).  This isn't tagged as 8086 either, so there's no reason not to use 2 or 3 operand (`imul dest, src, imm`) to save on moving things aside out of eax / edx (used implicitly by `mul` and `div`).

Comment: I agree.  Once I realized that al and ah are the low and high of ax then the solution is obviously simply to use another register.

Comment: mov al,5
    mov bl,4 
    mul bl 

    mov cx,35 
    mov dl,7 
    div dl

Answer (score 1):

To answer the primary question:  You can use `imul reg, reg, imm` to do your multiply into a different register.  Or you can just `mov ecx, eax` to save your result in a register you don't need for `div`.

---

Since you didn't say where the data has to come from, the obvious thing to do is perform the calculation at assemble time.

```
mov eax,  5*4 + 35/7
```

---

If you still wanted to compute at run time, you need to start with the values in immediate constants, in registers, or in memory.  It's convenient to illustrate a mix of those here (since `div` has no immediate-operand form)

It's usually best to use the default operand size, which is 32bits in 32 and 64bit mode.  8bit ops are not usually slower, though.

```
mov    eax, 35
div    byte [seven]     ; al = ax/7, ah=ax%7.  wider operand sizes divide edx:eax by the src.

mov    cl, 5
lea    eax, [ecx*4 + eax]  ; al = cl*4 + al.  Ignore the garbage in the high bits.
; result in al

section .rodata
seven:   db 7
```

`div` is slow, so [compilers replace divides by constants with multiplies by funky constants, and shift the result](http://goo.gl/MUppw0), because that's possible with 2's complement overflow.

See [Which 2's complement integer operations can be used without zeroing high bits in the inputs, if only the low part of the result is wanted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in) for justification for using `lea` to multiply by 4 and add, without clearing the high bits.

Comment: I should point out that my edit didn't alter the question any. The addition of tag x86 doesn't say explicitly whether it is 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit code. The tag itself is worded to encompass all three of them. I'd add a specific processor tag once the OP answers the question I posed under the question. Still possible they are targeting 16-bit code. I have a suspicion it is 16-bit code based on his university and some of the curriculum.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I realized that after looking at the edit more carefully.  I hadn't figured out from the garbled original that the OP knew the problem was clobbering ax.  Also, yeah I figured he was probably writing 16bit code, but 16bit is dumb so I purposely avoided encouraging it.  I didn't look at his user page to try to figure out what university he was attending.  multi-operand `imul` is still available in 16bit mode on normal CPUs, and I had been guessing it was a DOS question, not crappy 8086 without 386 features.

Comment: He added a comment, and I'm not surprised it was emu8086, so the target is 16-bit code. As for the multioperand versions of imul  didn't start appearing until 80286 (some were added in the 386). I don't believe any of the multi operand variants work on emu8086 as it was designed as an 8086 environment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yup, I know multi-operand `imul` wasn't in 8086. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings says imul immedate was added with 186. It doesn't say anything about 2-operand imul. :/  My phrasing was clumsy, but like I said, I was guessing the OP was using DOS, but not that he was stuck with 8086. So I was trying to point out some neat ways of doing stuff that 8086 doesn't have. Answers that do things the old, slow way don't clue people in. If people want crippled answers, they need to specifically ask for them.  And then I usually don't bother answering.