# Can the multiplication of two unsigned shorts really lead to undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have spent some time trawling this site; in particular this question: [Is ((a + (b & 255)) & 255) the same as ((a + b) & 255)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751662/is-a-b-255-255-the-same-as-a-b-255)

In doing so, I've been led to the conclusion that

```
int main()
{
    unsigned short i = std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max();
    unsigned short j = i;
    auto y = i * j;
}
```

can lead to undefined behaviour due to a type promotion of `i` and `j` to `int` which subsequently overflows upon the multiplication! Perhaps `i` and `j` need not to even be this large.

**My conclusion is that, for example, on a system where `unsigned short` is 16 bits and `int` is 32 bits, the behaviour can be *undefined*.**

Am I correct here?

Comment: no, it's defined behavior (witch becomes same value as `(i*j)%std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max()`) without consider overflow

Comment: @apple no, that is not correct.

Comment: It's a pity that you can't downvote a comment.

Comment: @Yakk @ FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy can you explain to me why it is undefined? I don't think `i` and `j` fit in `prvalue` as @krzaq quote

Comment: @appleapple They'll undergo the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion first.

Comment: So then the following question arises: how can we avoid the overflow here? Is there any way of forcing the compiler to keep things `unsigned short` throughout the computation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and your example is likely to be undefined on most desktop architectures.

For the sake of this example, let's assume that `int` is 32-bit 2's complement type and `unsigned short` is 16-bit.

I'm using N4140 for the quotes.

Before multiplication, both values are promoted to `int`:

> § 4.5 [conv.prom] / 1
>
> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or
>   wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
>   int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type;

Then:

> § 5 [expr] / 4
>
> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined.

Since the result of 65535 * 65535 (4294836225) is not defined in our 32-bit `int` (with value range [-2147483648,2147483647]), the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: It overflows on my PC where the above example is compiled with VS 2013.

Comment: Great answer! I think the promotion rules are one of the worst things (in terms of language design) in C that unfortunately got adopted by C++. They are the source of countless number of subtle bugs. Fortunately the compilers can warn sometime.

Comment: Wouldn't the type of the expression get promoted to `unsigned int` if the value cannot fit into an int?

Comment: @0x499602D2 nope, I quoted The relevant paragraphs

Comment: @vsoftco in case promotion alter the value (which is the only issue really), you can use the -Wconversion as explained here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html