# assembly lea instruction of int *q = p++ and int c = a++

Tags: c, assembly, x86

In order to deepen the impression about how the " (*p)++ " works, I wrote some test codes like:

```
int main()
{
  int  a = 3;
  int *p = &a;
  int b = (*p)++;
  int *q = p++;
  int c = a++;
  int d = c++;
  printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d, d = %d, p = %#x, q = %#x\n",a, b, c, d, p, q);
}
```

OUTPUT IS: a = 5, b = 3, c = 5, d = 4, p = 0xc6dc3490, q = 0xc6dc348c

But my question is about the assembly (codes are in orders and not off and on):

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48

;int a = 3 :
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], 3

;int *p = &a :
        lea     rax, [rbp-36]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax

;int b = (*p)++ :
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        lea     ecx, [rax+1]               ;Flag1
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax

;int *q = p++ :
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]     ;Flag2
        lea     rdx, [rax+4]               ;Flag3
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax

;int c = a++;
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-36]
        lea     edx, [rax+1]               ;Flag4
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax

;int d = c++;
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
        lea     edx, [rax+1]               ;Flag5
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-32], eax

... ... (ignore some)
```

Please pay attention to the "Flagx" lines which make me confused.
From above , we know that 
when pointer:   **int *q = p++** :

```
lea     rdx, [rax+4]    ;Flag3
```

Here, 'lea' seems to read the addr value store in 'rax' and +4. then pass to 'rdx'.
while:   **int c = a++** or **int d = c++** :

```
lea     edx, [rax+1]    ;Flag4/Flag5
```

Here,  'lea' seems to read the content of the addr value store in 'rax' (which is 3 here), and +1, come to 4 and pass to 'edx'.  
**But!** the point is that '**rax**' in these two statments are the **same one**. They're all from

```
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]   ;Flag2
```

As we can see, they ( Flag3 and Flag4/Flag5 )  look very similar, but they work very differently base on a same 'rax', how come ?  Can the 'lea' instruction distinguish between 'rdx' and 'edx / ecx' and turn out different results ?  
Thank you very much.

Comment: You want to look at [**What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction).

Comment: thank you , but i think that i may not have described my question clearly.  i want to know why after "lea  rdx, [rax+4]"  , 'rdx' stores 'rax' value(which means an address like: 0xeafffac0 ) +4, and after "lea  edx, [rax+1]" , 'edx' stores the content of 'rax' address value (here is : 3 , not the address any more) +1.

Comment: @ProbHunter Feel free to [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: @Stargateur  thank you and i have make some changes to my post, hoping to make my question more clearer this time. This's the 1st time i post a question on stackoverflow and my english's not good enough, thank you for your understanding..

Comment: If you compile with optimization enabled, there's a lot fewer instructions to look at.  All the unnecessary loads/store go away.  e.g. `int foo(int a) { return a+1; }` [will compile to `lea eax, [rdi+1]` / `ret`](https://godbolt.org/g/sSVha2).  (Or with the Windows ABI where the first integer arg goes in RCX, `lea eax, [rcx+1]`.)

Comment: Also note that `add` and `lea` can be used with garbage in the high bits, because carry propagates from LSB to MSB.  So the value in `eax` after `lea eax, [rdi+1]` only depends on `edi`.  (This matters for function args, since the caller is allowed to leave garbage in the high 32 bits.  You don't need an address-size prefix (`lea eax, [edi+1]`) or zero-extension (`mov eax,edi` / `inc eax`)).  See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

> *Here, 'lea' seems to read the content of the addr value store in 'rax' (which is 3 here), and +1, come to 4 and pass to 'edx'.*

No, you are mistaken. `lea edx, [rax+1]` doesn't change `rax`. `rax` is already `3` before the `lea` instruction is evaluated.

> *But! the point is that 'rax' in these two statments are the same one. They're all from `mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]`*

No, you are mistaken. `rax` is being set by `mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-36]`.

Different parts of the general purpose registers can be referenced using different names.

```
   64                  32        16    8    0
    |                   |         |    |    |
    v                   v         v    v    v
     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
     +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

     |<------------------------------------->| rax
                         |<----------------->| eax
                                   |<------->|  ax
                                   |<-->|       ah
                                        |<-->|  al
```

This means that when you write to `eax`, you are also writing to the bottom half of `rax` (and the top half gets zeroed).

So,

```
                                         ; rax       eax          rdx       edx
; q = p++                                ; +----+----+----+----+  +----+----+----+----+
A1      mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]   ; |                 p |  |               ??? |
A2      lea     rdx, [rax+4]             ; |                 p |  |               p+4 |
A3      mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdx   ; |                 p |  |               p+4 |
A4      mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax  ; |                 p |  |               p+4 |
; c = a++                                ; |                 p |  |               p+4 |
B1      mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-40]  ; |       0 |       a |  |               p+4 |
B2      lea     edx, [rax+1]             ; |       0 |       a |  |       0 |     a+1 |
B3      mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-40], edx  ; |       0 |       a |  |       0 |     a+1 |
B4      mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax  ; |       0 |       a |  |       0 |     a+1 |
                                         ; +----+----+----+----+  +----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: You have a bit of an issue. In 64-bit x86 code, when the destination of an instruction is a 32-bit register, the processor automatically zero extended it into the upper 32-bits of the 64-bit register. So `????` in the bottom half of your table is actually a known value of `0`.

Comment: @Michael Petch, Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @ikegami thank you for your well text and graphics, this's really helpful. But due to my poor expression in english, i may have not made my question clear, i had changed my post some minutes ago, heading for more wonderful answers. Thank you all!

Comment: @ikegami  I have got my answer after your now comment, Thank you very much! that's what i really want to know. As what you said, value of ' rax ' had been changed through  ' eax '.  :)

Answer (score 2):

`p` and `q` are pointers to `int` and the size of an `int` is **4** on your platform. So incrementing `p` actually increments its value by **4**.

```
int *q = p++;

   mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]     ; rax = p
   lea     rdx, [rax+4]               ; same as rdx = rax + 4
   mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdx     ; p = rdx
   mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax    ; q = rax
```

`c` is an `int`. So incrementing `a` actually just increments its value by **1**.

```
c = a++;

   mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-40]    ; rax = a (yes modifying eax actually modifies rax)
   lea     edx, [rax+1]               ; same as edx = rax + 1
   mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-40], edx    ; a = edx
   mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax    ; c = eax (eax still contains the inital value of a)
```

[More details about the `LEA` instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction).

Comment: Re "*same as edx = rax + 1*", Or more relevant, same as edx = eax + 1.

Comment: The OP isn't wondering why sometimes `1`, sometimes `4` is added.

Answer (score -2):

In line `int *q = p++` the address pointer is getting incremented. As you know the size of int is 4 bytes and size of int is size of pointer variable, so in assembly code you can see `lea     rdx, [rax+4]`.
But in line `int c = a++` the value of variable `a` is getting incremented. So in assembly code you can see `lea     edx, [rax+1]`.

**Note:** Size of `int` may vary from compiler to compiler. But as per `GCC` based compilers and in your case `int` is 4 byte long

Comment: Re "*size of int is size of pointer variable*", Not in the OP's case.

Comment: @ikegami x86, mean 32 bit no ? Oh never mind fuz add it just now.

Comment: @Stargateur, `p` is read/written as a `QWORD`, which means 64 bits. `rax` is used to store it, which is a 64-bit register. /// Comparitively, `a` is read/written as a `DWORD`, which means 32 bits. `eax` is used to store it, which is a 32-bit register.

Comment: @cse, Re "*How you can say that?*", I've already explained in a follow-up comment.

Comment: The OP isn't wondering why sometimes `1`, sometimes `4` is added.